# Is there a way to close down a port used by a service during shutdown or boot?

Tags: linux, networking, port, services, sockets

I have some service `listen.service` which makes the machine act as a TCP server which other clients can connect to. The problem is once the service starts up, it doesn't actually do anything for about 5 minutes because the port was previously used. If I just run the program from command line I could kill the process ID, however I don't have one/can't find one. I am assuming services do not have a PID I can kill. I was using `netstat -ap | grep :<portNumber>` to locate the open port used by service but no usable PID was given.

So to clarify my service is some program file which sets an IP and Port as a socket and act as a listening server. If I reboot the machine the service restarts, however nothing happens because the socket/port is still open somehow. After about 5 minutes it starts working as expected. Is there a way I can shutdown that socket/port on boot?

Comment: I think netstat shows *symbolic* service name for the port (from /etc/services), not numeric, but grep searches for the number and obviously fails. Use `netstat -nap`, or better `netstat -lnpt` or `-lnpu` to search for listening tcp or udp service, respectively, then you'll be able to grep by port number.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov the ```netstat -lnpt``` command displays the socket in LISTEN state, but for the PID/Program name its just ```-```

Comment: You had insufficient privileges to see it then. Run it under `sudo` or as root.